# Über das Wort "Schlautelefon"

Tags: single-word-request

Das Wort "Schlautelefon", welches übrigens nicht einmal von der Autokorrektur anerkannt wird, habe ich bisher mehrmals in Artikeln gesehen, obwohl es weder in Duden noch bei DWDS zu finden ist. Handelt es sich hierbei um ein **standardsprachliches**, **umgangssprachliches** oder **jugendsprachliches** Wort?

Comment: Bist du sicher, dass du nicht ein *Schlauchtelefon* meinst? Dies wird als Kinderspielzeug verkauft - eine Art kommerzialisiertes *Schnurtelefon* oder auch *Dosentelefon*. Uh... ach so... sorry... offenbar ist ein Smartphone gemeint. Na ja. Offenbar ein Attempt, diese ongoing Amerikanisierung zu downslowen. Warum nur?

Comment: Schlautelefon wird manchmal von meist technophoben Zeitgenossen als allzu wörtliche Übersetzung des Smartphones verwendet. Ich würde es auf eine Stufe stellen mit der Verwendung von "Windoof", wenn abfällig über Windows geredet wird. Also eher eine absichtliche Falschübersetzung, um etwas ins Lächerliche zu ziehen. In welche Kategorie das damit gehört, kann ich nicht sagen.

Comment: **Schlaubifon** sollte man die Dinger nennen, nach dem Wichtigtuer, der ohne nicht leben kann.

Comment: @Gerhardh - Ich würde hier unterscheiden zwischen Technophobie (oder Misotechnie) und dem Streben danach, für globalenglische Wörter auch deutschwurzlige Alternativen anzubieten. Letzteres kann man ja tun ohne ersterem erlegen zu sein. - *Schlautelefon* ist allerdings zugegebenerweise kein gutes Wort... zu lang, und außerdem ist das Smartphone ja nicht schlau (dazu müsste es denken können) sondern einfach nur universell. - Wenn schon dann vielleicht ***Rechenquatsche***.

Comment: Man kann also zusammenfassend sagen, dass das kein standardsprachliches Wort ist, noch ein umgangssprachliches. Eher ein deppensprachliches. <g>

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Bei den Fundstellen, aus denen ich das Wort kenne, handelte es sich meist um Beiträge von Personen, die gegen die Technik ins Feld gezogen sind. Es mag natürlich sein, dass die auch gleichzeitig ablehnend der Verwendung englischer Begriffe gegenüberstehen.

Comment: Ich wäre davon ausgegangen, dass das Wort eher scherzhaft verwendet wird. Die Übersetzung ist offensichtlich zu wörtlich, um zu funktionieren. Ein ähnlicher Fall ist *Winzigweich* für Microsoft.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Unterscheiden, globalenglische, deutschwurzlige,  zugegebenerweise und Rechenquatsche sind aber nicht zu lang? Oder rechnen wir nach Silben? Und Rechen die angemessene Übersetzung für smart?

Comment: Ich verwende das Wort *Schlaufon* durchaus auch unironisch...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es ist eine umgangssprachliche Wortkreation, die in ursprünglich spöttischer Absicht direkt aus dem Englischen übersetzt, bisher nicht in die Standardsprache Eingang gefunden hat und auf Grund der kleineren Akzeptanz von Smartphones in älteren Generationen eher von älteren Menschen als in der Jugendsprache verwendet wird.

Comment: Schöne Definition. Aber ich frage mich, ob du die abschließende Behauptung (vor allem ältere...) belegen kannst (von mir aus mit eigenen Erfahrungen), oder ob das doch eher nur eine Vermutung ist.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ich kenne viele junge Menschen und bei denen macht sich keiner einen Kopf das Teil auf Deutsch zu übersetzen.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht ob ich von der Erklärung besonders überzeugt bin. Die ältesten Belege, die ich im Netz von "Schlautelefon" finden kann, sind aus 2011/2012, wo das Wort eher in einem neutralen Zusammenhang verwendet wird. Eine fast zwanghafte Muss-Übersetzung von englischen Begriffen verbinde ich eher mit Fach- oder akademischen Kreisen und nicht wirklich mit älteren Menschen.

Comment: Ich kenne einige junge Menschen, die "Smarti" sagen. "Schlautelefon" klingt wie 90er, und außerdem neigen die Menschen zu kurzen Wörtern, da ist das viel zu lang...

Comment: @jarnbjo: ich kenne eher Schlaufon/-phon, das hat vor 9 Jahren auch mal einer erfasst: https://www.mundmische.de/bedeutung/33908-Schlaufon, im OpenThesaurus erst 2020 https://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/Schlauphon, Verwendung 2012 http://www.einfacherweise.com/2012/03/apfel-ei-oder-telefon.html, hier auch 2012 https://stadt-bremerhaven.de/sms-am-pc-lesen-und-verschicken-mit-android-und-mightytext-oder-desknotifier-moeglich/ oder hier 2013 https://blog.imagcon.de/2013/01/izettle-nein-danke/ und auch 2013 http://www.fusselforum.de/viewtopic.php?p=63829 sprechen für ca. 2010 als Entstehungszeit

Answer (score 0):

Das wäre dann wohl eher "Schmarti" oder

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Das liest sich irgendwie zwischen zu kurze Antwort und Kommentar. Abgesehen dass die Referenz "Das" und der Satzpunkt fehlt. Wäre es möglich, für eine taugliche Antwort es etwas vollständiger zu beschreiben, was gemeint ist? Z.B. indem Standard-Begriffe wie Smartphone statt "Schmarti" verwendet werden?

Comment: Wilkommen! Der mit "Your Answer" überschriebene Kasten ist nur für Antworten auf die ursprüngliche Frage.